# How to open a JAVA servlet file on Windows whose name is too long?

Tags: java, windows, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I need to see the translated JSP into the Servlet. 
So, within ***TOMCAT's work/Catalina*** directory, when i tried to open the Java Servlet file, it throws an error.

I have already gone through this [description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146290/how-do-you-delete-a-file-whose-name-is-too-long#)
In fact, I am unable to perform any of the actions on this particular file(***rename, delete, move, copy***)

I have attached screenshot for the same. 
[image: ***Translated JSP***]

Comment: do you just want to open the file in an editor, or serve it through Tomcat?

Comment: @eis: Just need to open it.

Comment: You can use `8.3 file name` format of Windows. Look at my answer. I hope it'll solve your problem.

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari how is this related to programming, then? Or should it be a superuser issue instead?

Comment: @eis: Oh! ya that make sense. I am so sorry. Was just in a hurry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Windows* provides **[8.3 file name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename)**. Also knows as **[short filename](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename)** or **[SFN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename)** which have *at most eight characters, optionally followed by a period "." and a filename extension of at most three characters*.

```
Windows supports long file names up to 255 characters in length. Windows also 
generates an MS-DOS-compatible (short) file name in 8.3 format to allow MS-DOS-based
or 16-bit Windows-based programs to access the files.
```

You can read about this on [How Windows Generates 8.3 File Names from Long File Names - Support Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/142982) & [How to convert a long filename to a short filename](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename#How_to_convert_a_long_filename_to_a_short_filename).

On the *superuser.com* many solutions available to solve problem with long file names. You should have look at this post [Tool for deleting directories with path/names too long for normal delete](https://superuser.com/questions/78434/tool-for-deleting-directories-with-path-names-too-long-for-normal-delete).

I hope this helps you.